# pysfml breaks on runtime while displaying a render window

Tags: python, python-3.x, sfml

im using pySfml with python3.3 x64
when i simply want to display a window it breaks . it runs normally and everything is working for 2-3 seconds . then the window gets non responding while my pytho script is actually still working and everything is fine there .

```
import sfml as sf

win = sf.RenderWindow(sf.VideoMode(500,500),"hi")
win.clear()
win.display()

input()
```

so , does anyone has any experience with this problem ? its really annoying .
to be more accurate im using python 3.3.2
and pysfml 1.3.0

many thanks in advance

edit : just tried the same code this time with python2.7 32 bit
it happened again . whats going on ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tried this and it worked :

```
import sfml as sf

win = sf.RenderWindow(sf.VideoMode(100,100),"hi")

while(1):
    for i in win.events :
        pass
    win.clear()
    win.display()
```

looks like i HAVE TO always empty the event queue somehow . even when i have nothing to do with events .